# React-native-admob-native-ads not working on real device without testID and iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, admob

I have installed 'react-native-admob-native-ads' plugin with 0.4.1 version and react-native version is 0.64.2.

i can't test ad without testAdId in Android,
iOS we can't test with testAdId in simulator.

any one can help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, current can't use Ad on react-native.

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5329#issuecomment-843272057